# pass value between two controllers in two jsp files angularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp

I'm using .factory to pass value between two controllers which are in two different jsp files. Here is the code.

```
//this is .factory part
var app=angular.module("abs", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap","ngCookies"]);

app.factory('cromeesService', function() {
  var took_live = null;

  var addTook = function(newObj) {        
      took_live = newObj;        
  };

  var getTook = function(){       
      return took_live;       
  };  

  return {
    addTook: addTook,
    getTook: getTook,
  };

}); 

//this is the first controller in first jsp file. 
//this controller makes API call and then addTook value to took_live in .factory
...some other lines...

<script>     
var app = angular.module("abs");    
app.requires.push('ngPrettyJson');
    app.controller("firstController", function($scope,$http,$interval,cromeesService){          

        $scope.message = "some message";

        var onUserComplete = function(response){
            $scope.re = response.data;    
            debugger;
            cromeesService.addTook($scope.re.took);
        };

        var apiCallGET = function(){
            $http.get("url to somewhere")
                 .then(onUserComplete); 
        };          
        $interval(apiCallGET,1000,1);                                   
    });         
</script>

//here is the 2nd controller in a 2nd jsp file
//this controller call getTook() to grab took_live value and use in this controller

app.controller('tileController',function($scope,cromeesService){        
    var tookvalue = cromeesService.getTook();
}
```

the first controller is able to pass value to took_live in .factory successfully. but when the 2nd controller call getTook() the returned value is reset to null instead of the value that the 1st controller added. it appears to me that the took_live can't hold the value that the 1st controller passed into. the .factory can send value to either controller but can't pass value between the two controllers.

I tested this in a separated environment where only angularJS exists excluding jsp files, it works. is this related to jsp as well?

Comment: create plnkr seems to be working fine https://plnkr.co/edit/elnPOIrIPx76qRDNy58j?p=preview

Comment: I also tested this way and it works but it won't work when the two controllers are in two jsp files. is there something I missed here when putting angularJS and JSP togather?